# How are Activities and Fragments tied together in the lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

when i create blank Activity with fragment in android studio what is actually done ! Specifically how they attached together ? in which line of code and how this done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is actually done?

It creates a template out of the following files.

- One `Activity` with a layout
- One `ActivityFragment` with a layout
- One `strings.xml` value for the title of the Activity
- One `res/menu` resource for the Toolbar menu
- Adds an `<activity>` section to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: Screenshot]

> How are they attached together? In which line of code?

In the `onCreate` for the Activity, you set the layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Which attaches the Fragment with a `<fragment>` tag like this, which is basically a `FrameLayout`.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="com.androidstack.app.MainActivityFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Google's docs should help you understand a bit.

However a short version is this:

in the Activity's `onCreate`:

- Activity's view is drawn.
- Fragment is instantiated.

in the fragments's `onAttach`:

- Fragment is attached to Activity

in the fragment's `onCreate`:

- fragment is created

in the Fragment's `onViewCreated`:

- Fragment's view is drawn.

Comment: thanks for explanation
and now i reading Google's docs for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

Just think of it as an activity within an activity. It is essentially the same things as changing the `activity` by using an `intent` but is just within it. So there is a `parent activity`, within it is the `frame` or `layout` that holds the fragment. When the `parent activity` is done loading it will begin to load the contents of the `layout`'s, which is your fragment. Contents of that `fragment` can be accessed by using `v.OnclickListener` and so on

Comment: i was trying to find in which line they attached and i found it so really thank you for your help

Comment: No problem! Good luck!